# No me funciona un elemento duplicado

Tags: javascript

Estoy aprendiendo sobre JavaScript y estoy creando elementos HTML dinámicamente, y cuando creo un elemento la librería y un JavaScript aparte me dejan de funcionar.

```js
function duplicate(){
    let campos = document.createElement('div');
    campos.innerHTML = `
    <div class="form-duplicate" id="ecopy" ><div class="formulario-principal" id="formulario-dividido">
    <div class="inputs">
        <input class="input_form" type="text" placeholder="Nombre Completo">
        <input class="input_form" type="text" placeholder="Identificacion">
        <input class="input_form" type="text" placeholder=" Telefono">
        <button onclick="duplicate()" class="btn" type="button" id="btn-duplicate" name="btn-duplicate">+</button>
    </div>
        <div class="input-field">
            <i class="large material-icons prefix">search</i>
            <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete inputsearch">
            <label for="autocomplete-input">Buscar Examen</label>
            <button type="button" class="btn-add">+</button>
                <div class="li-container">
                    <ul>
                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div> <br><br><br>`;
document.getElementById('duplicates').appendChild(campos);
}
```

Js de la librería:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var options ={
        data: {
            "google": null,
            "Facebook": null,
            "instagram": null,
            "LinkedIn": null,
          },
    }

    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete');
    var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(elems, options);
  });
```

Mi error está en que el me duplica todo el div que le estoy diciendo pero en el input con id autocomplete-input tiene una libreria que es un buscador dinamico entonces una vez copiado este me deja de funcionar. Espero haber explicado bien

Comment: Cómo se le está aplicando la libreria al input con id autocomplete-input? Además comentar que en un documento html no deberia haber ids repetidos. Ya que es un identificador único

Comment: @ClintonTapiaLagar La librería se le esta aplicando a través del id

Comment: Código de cómo se le está aplicando?.Imagino que es una funcion o parecido que usa la libreria.

Comment: @ClintonTapiaLagar Acabe de agregar el Js de la librería para el funcionamiento

Comment: Ya entiendo. Lo que tienes que hacer es volver a ejecutar la libreria. Busca una forma en su documentación

Comment: La primera vez que se abre la pagina funciona muy bien, la libreria aplica solo a los inputs existentes en ese momento. Pero cuando presionas el boton de duplicar se crea un nuevo input que la libreria no lo detecta, por lo cual en la documentacion de la librería busca una forma de reiniciar antes de terminar la funcion duplicate

Comment: @ClintonTapiaLagar He estado viendo la documentación del Autocomplete pero la verdad las opciones que ofrecen son como para una personalización de si quiero que sea x cantidad de elementos que no quiero que se autocomplete

Comment: Entonces talvez solo sea ejecutar de nuevo la funcion que está en el evento DOMContentLoaded

Comment: Prueba creando una nueva funcion con el codigo de la funcion pasada a DOMContentLoaded. Luego antes de terminar la funcion duplicate la ejecutas

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135745/discussion-between-juan-manuel-and-clinton-tapia-lagar).